# Simple Injector for Unit Of Work and EF DbContext per Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simple-injector

I'm using the UoW pattern and i've used Simple Injector to dependency injection.
I've registered the UoW class like `container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);` and the UoW class receives a DbContext in the constructor like:

```
    private readonly LPCContext _lpcContext;        

    public UnitOfWork(LPCContext lpcContext)
    {
        _lpcContext = lpcContext;
    }
```

Where LpcContext is a DbContext type.

My question is: Since i want to have a DbContext per request, do i still need to register it in Simple Injector? If so, how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `LPCContext` is a concrete type with a single constructor, technically speaking, you don't have to register it, because Simple Injector can auto-create it for you, and since the `UnitOfWork` is created as scoped, it will drag allong the `LPCContext` as scoped lifestyle as well. However...

Simple Injector will auto-register a concrete unregistered type for you using the transient lifestyle. But now your scoped registration of `UnitOfWork` depends on a registration with a shorer lifestyle (transient), Simple Injector will throw an exception, explaining there is a [Lifestyle Mismatch](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/LifestyleMismatches.html).

Although in your particular case this wouldn't be a problem per see, it is still important to fix the problem, because it can easily lead to problems later on, when you start injecting the `LPCContext` into other consumers as well. In that case, each consumer will get its own `LPCContext` instance, which is typically not what you want.

So to solve this, it's best to register the `LPCContext` class explicitly using the scoped lifestyle:

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
container.Register<LPCContext>(() => new LPCContext(conString), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Comment: That's what i am going to do.
Thank you @Steven.